# Where is the Muktware Ubuntu Manual installed?

Tags: software-installation

I installed "Muktware Ubuntu Manual" using the Ubuntu Software Center. There is no indication how to open and read the book. How do I find it on my system?

Shouldn't there be something on the launcher?

Comment: did you check your ubuntuone folders?  reference: http://www.muktware.com/articles/3556/muktware-ubuntu-manual#.UHrVfuA0nd4

Answer (score 2):

It is in the `/opt` directory. `dpkg -L muktware-ubuntu-manual` command is saying this

```
....
.... 
/opt
/opt/muktware-ubuntu-manual
/opt/muktware-ubuntu-manual/ubuntu-manual.pdf
```

So, the pdf file is in the `/opt/muktaware-ubuntu-manual` folder.

You can also launch if by typing "muktware" in the dash.

[image: Muktware in dash]